# How to avoid conflict of same class names in BEM?

Tags: css, bem

I'm working on a website using BEM methodology for maintaining my CSS code. Here is some HTML code:

```
<div>
    <form class="sc-campaign-form__test-wrapper" id="test-wrapper-1">
        <input type="text" class="sc-campaign-form__test-input" />
        <input type="submit" class="sc-campaign-form__test-submit" />
    </form>
    <form class="sc-campaign-form__test-wrapper" id="test-wrapper-2">
        <input type="text" class="test-wrapper__test-input" />
        <input type="submit" class="test-wrapper__test-submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I think that from BEM point `test-wrapper-2` is more right but I'm afraid to make conflict if I bundle everything into one big CSS file because `test-wrapper__test-input` looks very common. Though I want to have different styling for different test-wrappers. Which way would be more appropriate?

Comment: Why don't you use a different class name? If they're different enough to style differently, they're different enough to warrant a different class name...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That makes the markup more complicated. Even in this example, I had to make not `campaign-form` but `sc-campaign-form`. Actually, it's supposed to be `scheduler-campaign-form` but that's too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to guess the right way without seeing the layout. But I'll try.

1. Try to avoid such entities as wrappers (see https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#how-do-i-make-an-html-wrapper).
2. Please give a try to mixes (https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes)
3. Don't be afraid to have long classnames, actually it's better than abbreviations like `sc`. It's much harder to remember what does it mean.

So a result I'd suggest something like this:

```
<div class="campaign-form">
    <form class="form campaign-form__form">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" />
        <input type="submit" class="form__submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

So here you have `campaign-form` block with abstract universal `form` block inside mixed with an element `form` of `campaign-form` (that's the selector you'd use to provide specific for `campaign-form` styling).

If you also need to tune styling of form elements you can add mixes to the elements as well:

```
<div class="campaign-form">
    <form class="form campaign-form__form">
        <input type="text" class="form__input campaign-form__input" />
        <input type="submit" class="form__submit campaign-form__submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

As a result all the universal styles will be kept in reusable `form` + `form__input` + `form__submit` and everything specific to `campaign-form` in it's own elements. So you can easily reuse basic form styling wherever you like.